# How to calculate length of HTTPContent

Tags: .net, rest

I am working on some code that can send HTTP Requests using .Net Framework.
It can send form/data contents that can contain both StringContents or ByteArray- / StreamContents.

Now some interface that I call expects a Content-Length header on the request. How can I calculate the whole length of a `MultipartContent`. I tried calling `.TryComputeLength()`, but this method is internal.

My Code to build the Multipart-Content:

```
MultipartFormDataContent multiPartContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();

if (contents.Attachments.Count > 0)
{
    pof = LogMessage("Adding Attachment to Multipart-Content");
    
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, STGMedia> attachmentKVP in contents.Attachments)
    {
        STGMedia medium = attachmentKVP.Value;
        contentLength += medium.MediaStream.Length;
        multiPartContent.Add(GenerateAttachmentContent(medium, ActivityConfiguration.AttachmentFormat, medium.MediaType.MediaTypeMimeType), attachmentKVP.Key, medium.Name);
    }
}
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in contents.FormData)
{
    multiPartContent.Add(new StringContent(kvp.Value), kvp.Key);
}

multiPartContent.Headers.ContentLength = contentLength;
```

But the `content-Length` that I calculate here is wrong. The string Content length is not included

Comment: As `TryComputeLength()` is protected, you could derive a custom `MultipartFormDataContent` which could expose the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer this question. HttpClient indeed sets the Header itself properly when sending the request. The problem was the expect-continue header. The recipient could deal with this header.